# JsonCpp ambiguous overload only in Windows

Tags: c++, json, windows, overloading, ambiguous

I need to read a json file with jsoncpp library.

I have this file:

`{"one":false,"two":[{"id":"first"},{"id":"second"}],"three":550}`

If i need to read only the first id of "two" element, i use:

```
std::string contents; //Contain the file
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse(contents, root, false);
std::string aux = root["two"][0]["id"].asString();
```

It works fine in Linux, but when i try it in Windows i have this error:

`error: ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' in 'root.Json::Value::operator[](((const char*)"two"))[0]'`

Why it happens and how can i fix this? Thanks.

Solved: There are two `operator[]`, one with an `int` as parameter and other with a `const char` as parameter, and the compiler doesn't know who to use in Windows, but yes in Linux. Now i use `[0u]` instead `[0]` to indicate a number as parameter and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This drove me crazy, until I stumbled upon this question, I mysteriously figured it out:
Just cast it to Json::Uint (for some reason), or use 'u':

```
MapEvent::MapEvent(Json::Value& val)
{
    operator_enum = val.get(0u, "").asString();
}
```

Comment: It's annoying and probably an API mistake, but at least it's mentioned [in the docs](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#af9e02b38f4e63e491c300c20b275bdd7).